# How to implement this scenario using Terminal? (in Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, command-line, permissions, sudo, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.5 (32 bit) in Oracle VM VirtualBox. I want to create some user groups. There will be 1 or 2 users in each user group. There will be a user group called `administration0` . [I am the administrator. The other users will be standard users]

There will be a folder called `Administration`. The folder path is: `/home`. 
Inside the folder, there are 2 sub-folders: `Alice` and `Gabi`.  Alice and Gabi will be in the same user group `administration0`. Alice will be able to go to `Administration` folder and he will have full permission inside his own folder `Alice` (by the way, he **cannot** delete his own folder, he only have full permissions **inside** his folder).  Alice will have **read-only** permission for `Gabi` folder and everything in it.

Similarly, Gabi will be able to go to `Administration` folder and he will have full permission inside his own folder `Gabi` (by the way, he **cannot** delete his own folder, he only have full permissions **inside** his folder).  Gabi will have read-only permission for `Alice` folder and everything in it.

There is a folder called `Managers`. Both Alice and Gabi will have **read-only** permission for `Managers` folder and everything in it.

Can two users from a user group have different permissions on a certain folder or different folders (using terminal)? How to implement these in Terminal? Please help...

Answer (score 2):

Some of what you describe can be managed via normal permissions by controlling the rights at the user or group level accordingly. For the first scenario however, by nature of giving Alice (a 'he' apparently, poor guy) full rights to /home/adm/alice means that Alice would likely own that folder and thus, be able to remove it.  To do this at the group level so the parent folders would be owned by a different administrator, say root, but still give individual rights to Alice or Gabi isn't achievable with standard permissions, which only control 'rwx' for the User, Group, and Others (everyone else).

For more fine-grained control, you would need to use Posix extended 
ACL's.

For more information in the context of Ubuntu, read this:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs

Hope that helps,

tca

Comment: I am the administrator in the system. I am gonna create groups with 1-2 users using Terminal. Can I give different permissions to two users from the same group for a certain folder or different folder?

Comment: Please reply anyone :(